# ¿Cómo pasar a una funcion de evento varios parametros en un componente React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Teniendo declarada la funcion de esta manera:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.funcion= this.funcion.bind(this)
}

funcion(evt , num) {
    console.log("Num: ",num)
    console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",evt.keyCode)
}
```

Quiero realizar esta funcion de la siguiente manera en cada caso, siendo "num" una variable distinta en cada caso:

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown={this.funcion(this, num)}/>
```

De esta manera no reconoce el evento, pero si el número. Mi duda es la forma de pasarle varios parametros a una función, no solamente el parámetro por defecto.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es la asignación del callback al evento onKeyDown, recuerda que dentro de { callback } callback es una expresión no un valor, al colocar this.fumcion(this,bar) estas ejecutando la función en lugar de enviar la referencia de la función, tal vez lo que intentas poner es

```
onKeyDown={this.funcion.bind(this, valor)}
```

Sin embargo en la función necesitas acceder al evento en este caso puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
onKeyDown={(evt) => this.funcion(evt, valor)}
```

Bind retorna una función dentro de la cual asigna el primer parámetro que envías a la variable interna 'this', por esta razón es válido declarar el callback de esa manera con bind ya que retorna la misma función, no la ejecuta en el segundo caso de igual manera al utilizar el operador arrow estoy colocando una expresión en este caso es una función inline que la utilizó como intermediaria para capturar el objeto event y a su vez enviar este objeto a la función

Comment: Por experiencia puedo comentar que este es el mejor método

Answer (score 1):

Te pego este ejemplo sin JSX.

Te comento:

```
this.funcion= this.funcion.bind(this)
```

Esto me parece antipattern. Si vas a asignar un método a cada instancia, mejor defínelo a nivel de clase para que todas las instancias tengan ese método.

Para resolver tu duda, lo mejor es crear un método que devuelva una función, esto gracias a las clausuras, te permite pasar valores diferentes de 'num' para el input.

```
this.funcionEventHandler(Math.random())
```

Esto te devuelve una función que es la que escucha el evento 'onKeyDown' pero en su interior puedes acceder al 'num' que le has pasado como parámetro gracias a las clausuras (ver más aquí: http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/lesson?id=1000&lang=es).

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Input Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Input Example</h1>
<div id="container">
</div>

<!-- The core React library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.0/dist/react.js"></script>
<!-- The ReactDOM Library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<script>
  var Input = React.createClass({
    funcion(evt , num) {
      console.log("Num: ", num);
      console.log("Codigo de tecla: ", evt.keyCode);
    },
    funcionEventHandler: function (num) {
      return (evt) => {
        this.funcion(evt, num);
      }
    },
    render: function () {
      return React.DOM.input({
        onKeyDown: this.funcionEventHandler(Math.random())
      });
    }
  });

  var InputFactory = React.createFactory(Input);
  ReactDOM.render(
    InputFactory(),
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
onKeyDown ={that.funcion.bind(that, num)}
```

Comment: Deberías explicar un poco más tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si pones "this.funcion(this, num)" estas activando esa función al hacer el *render* del componente y en el *onKeyDown* no estas metiendo la función sino el *return* de la función, por eso no te lo reconoce.

```
    <input type="text" onKeyDown={this.funcion(this, num)}/>
```

Para poder activar la función con el *onKeyDown* y poder pasarle un contenido de la variable diferente en "num" envolvemos en una función (*closure*) "this.funcion".

Te muestro algunas maneras de como hacerlo:

Ejemplo con arrow function:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    state = {};
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Esto te sobra si utilizas arrow 
        //this.funcion= this.funcion.bind(this);
    }

    funcion(evt , num) {
        console.log("Num: ",num);
        console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",evt.keyCode);
    }
  
    render() {
        return <input type="text" onKeyDown={(e) => {this.funcion(e, Math.random())}}/>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Input />,
    document.getElementById('componente')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="componente">
</div>
```

Si lo haces sin arrow function tienes que bindearle el contexto (this):

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
state = {};
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  //Esto te sobra si bindeas el conxtexto directamente.
   // this.funcion= this.funcion.bind(this)
}

funcion(evt, num) {
    console.log("Num: ",num);
    console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",evt.keyCode);
}

render() {
    return <input type="text" onKeyDown={(function (e) {this.funcion(e, Math.random())}).bind(this)}/>
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<Input />,
    document.getElementById('componente')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="componente">
</div>
```

Con bind, ojo tienes que cambiar el orden de los parámetros de la función, también he añadido un input para cambiar la variable num guardada en el estado del componente:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    state = {
        num: 0
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    funcion(num, evt) {
        console.log("Num: ",num);
        console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",evt.keyCode);
    }

    cambiarNum(e){
        this.setState({num: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="num" value={this.state.num} onChange={this.cambiarNum.bind(this)}/>
                <input type="text" onKeyDown={this.funcion.bind(this, this.state.num)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Input />,
    document.getElementById('componente')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="componente">
</div>
```

Ya que estoy os dejo el ejemplo de @noodle71 en JSX:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
    state = {
        num: 0
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.cambiarNum = this.cambiarNum.bind(this);
    }

    funcion(evt,num) {
        console.log("Num: ",num);
        console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",evt.keyCode);
    }

    funcionEventHandler(num) {
        return (evt) => {
            this.funcion(evt, num);
        }
    }

    cambiarNum(e){
        this.setState({num: e.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="num" value={this.state.num} onChange={this.cambiarNum}/>
                <input type="text" onKeyDown={this.funcionEventHandler(this.state.num)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Input />,
    document.getElementById('componente')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="componente">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer currying

```
funcion = (num, ...restoParametros) => (event)=> {
    console.log("Num: ",num)
    console.log("Codigo de tecla: ",event.keyCode)
}

<input type="text" onKeyDown={this.funcion(num)}/>
```